# Unable to disable button on click

Tags: javascript

I believe my code is correct. Any help will be appreciated:

EDIT: I have added the rest of the code. The other code works fine. It is just the button which does not function accordingly (when trying to disable it).

EDIT: Problem solved. Added a click function to the HTML. Thanks!

```
let ul = document.getElementById("list");
let buttonFirst = document.getElementById("Button1");
let itemArray = [];

buttonFirst.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  itemArray.push("Chocolate Cake");
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = "Chocloate Cake";
  ul.appendChild(li);
  buttonFirst.disabled = true;
  console.log(itemArray);
});
```

Comment: show your HTML! I'm willing to bet you made the mistake of putting your script in the head part

Comment: No. My script is good. The only issue I am having is with the button not being disabled.

Comment: Why do you have to preventDefault? Remove it will help.

Comment: show your HTML! I don't believe you. + read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MisterJojo No.

Comment: @TinySonhh tried it without default as well. No luck so far.

Comment: Also for web, please open browser, F12, add breakpoint and debug it to see if that command is called, or even the event is correctly triggered.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: @user123456789 I ran your code, and it works fine. The problem must be caused by other parts of your code which you have not posted.

Comment: @MisterJojo So you want me to paste an HTML code which is 200 lines long to prove that my script tag is in the correct place? Of which I have confirmed that it is? 

Okay.

Comment: @flamesdev The other parts of my code work fine. The button belongs to a shopping cart. When an item is added to the cart, the button disables itself. The cart functions perfectly fine, as does the other code. Which is why I am a bit perplexed as to why I am having this issue. 

Appreciate the help though, truly.

Comment: No, just provide the HTML part of this, this is the idea in **a minimal reproducible example. **

Comment: @user123456789 Do you know if the callback function is being called?

Comment: I've edited my code with the rest of the JS. I do welcome any feedback. Appreciate the help thus far.

Comment: @user123456789 check out some of the answers added here...and see if they work.

Comment: I got it to work. I added a click function to the HTML. Worked perfectly fine. Appreciate all the feedback.

Comment: @user123456789 upvote and mark the answer that helped you through this. Let it serve as a guide to others.

Comment: you just provide just more JS code, you didn't provide the **HTML** part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function disableButton(btn){
                document.getElementById(btn.id).disabled = true;
            }
</script>
```

Then in your HTML...you can reference the function like this;

```
<button type="button" id="btn1" onclick="disableButton(this)"> Disable Me! </button>
```

Comment: Perfect! My button functions properly now. Thank you!

Comment: @user123456789 please tick this as the answer and upvote if it helped you...it will guide others who need help in similar circumstances.

Comment: Can't you just do `btn.disabled = true` rather than getting the id of the button and then passing it as a parameter?

Comment: @flamesdev That is possible. What he was missing was calling the function from HTML. Check out the second snippet of code I added. I believe that was the actual obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

The button will be enabled until you click on it the first time.  Then it will become disabled.

Comment: That is the intention of the code. But it does not function according to the code. Even after clicking the button, it remains enabled.

Comment: What you posted works.  It is possible you got the selector wrong.  Is there any chance `let buttonFirst = document.getElementById("Button1");` should be `let buttonFirst = document.getElementById("button1");` with a lower case?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code , your problem is elsewhere.

```js
let buttonFirst = document.getElementById("Button1");
 
buttonFirst.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  buttonFirst.disabled = true;
});
```

```html
<button id="Button1" > buttonFirst </button>
```